# I want to check a best answer for the post I did before as a guest at Stack Exchange

Tags: support, faq, accepted-answer

The other day, I posted a question as a guest at the site of Stack Exchange. Some users answered for me, and I wrote "Thank you". But I forgot to decide the best answer at that time.

Now, I reinstalled Windows OS on my personal computer. And when I tried to check the best answer, I noticed I can't check the best answer. I can't become the guest as before (probably because the browser cookies disappeared when I reinstalled the OS. The browser is Internet Explorer.)

Whatever way, I want to check the best answer. What should I do?

Comment: +1 for your effort.

Comment: Welcome to Super User, and Stack Exchange! :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page to request the unregistered account you used earlier and the registered ones are merged, then select the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you!! I'll do as you say!

Answer (score 15):

The help article [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) indicates:

> If you have two accounts that you would like to join together, please edit the ‘about me’ section of each profile to say “merge keep” and "merge delete" and then [contact us](https://superuser.com/contact). You will need to provide links to the two profiles you would like to merge - we'll merge the one you annotated "merge delete" into the one you annotated "merge keep".
>
> If you can't remember how to log into one of your accounts, [go here](https://superuser.com/users/account-recovery) and enter the email address you used to create it.

So, as long as you've used a valid email address for previous account, you might be able to recover it (and help speed up the merge process).